# CRON JOB - Schedule Laravel command for different timezones - Manage users local time

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and I like to send notifications to users on `thursdays` at `8pm`

Let's say I have

1. User A in Tokyo
2. User B in London
3. User C in New York City

#### Questions

How should I set the CRON JOB so they all receive the notification at `8pm` in their local time?.

My server is in New York City

#### Code

`$schedule->command('sendNotifications')->dailyAt('20:00')->thursdays()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Logic can't be done just with just one: `$schedule->command('sendNotifications')` command and some parameters.

First step, if not already done, setup your server and add a Cron job that is calling the Laravel artisan command:

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

#### Option I

Second step change your schedule command to:

`$schedule->command('sendNotifications')->everyFifteenMinutes();` or
 `$schedule->command('sendNotifications')->everyThirtyMinutes();` or
 `$schedule->command('sendNotifications')->hourly();`

depending how exact you want to have it, because some time zones have 30 or 45 Minutes offset, see https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Now if your command `sendNotifications` is executed you have to build your logic there:

- Check if it is Thursday somewhere in the world, if not cancel
- Get timezones/counties where it is 20:00 at the moment, with tolerance if
  required
- Get all user in one of this timezones/counties and send
  the notification to them

#### Option II

Of course you can write 40+ different commands, one for each time zone,
and use the scheduler like this:

```
$schedule->command('sendNotifications_1')
          ->timezone('America/Chicago')
          ->thursdays()
          ->dailyAt('20:00');


$schedule->command('sendNotifications_2')
          ->timezone('Europe/London')
          ->thursdays()
          ->dailyAt('20:00');

$schedule->command('sendNotifications_3')
          ->timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
          ->thursdays()
          ->dailyAt('20:00');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know if laravel have this functionality.

But you can set cron job for every hour to check if that users current time(with time zone) is 8 AM and if we haven't sent notification to them.

And to those users, you can send the notification.