# CRON JOB - Schedule Laravel command for different timezones - Manage for different regions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, jobs

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I like to auto-generate Invoices should be generated auto from Monday - Sunday. 
every Sunday night at 23:59:00

Let's say I have

"23:59:00 according to the region time zone".

Every store is related to a region, from the region table you'll find the time zone.

Questions
How should I set the CRON JOB so I can generate invoices automatically according to the list of timezone I will get from the table?.

Comment: Hello, can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: The CRON JOB should be set up as usual, run `php artisan schedule:run` every minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions;

if you want it to be static, define each command with the corresponding timezone from your database. Different timezones may have same time such as `Europe/Amsterdam` and `Europe/Berlin`

```
$schedule->command('generate:report')->timezone('one-of-the-timezone')->at('23:59');
$schedule->command('generate:report')->timezone('another-timezone')->at('23:59');
$schedule->command('generate:report')->timezone('yet-another-timezone')->at('23:59');
$schedule->command('generate:report')->timezone('some-other-timezone')->at('23:59');
```

If you want it to be dynamic, make it run every 59. min hourly and try to match it with the timezones via using `hour`.

```
$schedule->command('generate:report')->hourlyAt(59);
```

Inside your command class;

```
public function handle(TimezoneRepository $timezoneRepository)
{
    $timezones = $timezoneRepository->getUniqueTimezones(); // the unique timezones in your database - cache if you want

    foreach ($timezones as $timezone) {
        $date = Carbon::now($timezone); // Carbon::now('Europe/Moscow'), Carbon::now('Europe/Amsterdam') etc..

        if ($date->hour === 23) { // you are in that timezone
            $currentTimezone = $date->getTimezone();
            dispatch(new ReportMaker($currentTimezone)); // dispatch your report maker job
        }
    }
}
```

With the dynamic one, you will hit to multiple timezones at one iteration(when `generate:report` is executed) as i said at then beginning.

- one of the possible flaw may be; if the execution of getting timezones etc takes more than 1 minute you may be in 00:00 instead of 23:59. It is better to calculate your report asynchronous and cache the list of timezones to not face problems while executing this loop.
- Another possible flaw;

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone);

> A few zones are offset by 30 or 45 minutes (e.g. Newfoundland Standard Time is UTC−03:30, Nepal Standard Time is UTC+05:45, Indian Standard Time is UTC+05:30 and Myanmar Standard Time is UTC+06:30).

If you want to cover any of these, then it is better to execute the command like this

```
$schedule->command('generate:report')->cron('14,29,44,59 * * * *');
```

and make both hour and minute comparison such as;

`$date->hour === 23 && $date->hour === 59`

Comment: and Basically I want to run that job from Monday to Sunday 
so how i can set that it runs automatically and get orders from Monday to Sunday and generate invoice base on different regions

Comment: @MuhammadIkramULMustafa as i stated in the example code you will dispatch ReportMaker and put that logic to generate invoices. In this job you will have timezone and inside the job you may fetch current day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [timezone() method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#timezones) in your task Schedulding

> Using the timezone method, you may specify that a scheduled task's
>   time should be interpreted within a given timezone:
>
> ```
> $schedule->command('report:generate')
>          ->timezone('America/New_York')
>          ->at('02:00')
> ```

Comment: it's mean I will get an array from DB for timezones and run schedule command within for loop of time zone and set my time at  23:59:00

Comment: hmm my solution is not very practical - you would have to create a schedule for every existing timezone.

Comment: But i have 10-15 time zone suppose so for every timezone I have to create it separately? We cannot do that with a loop or something 
Like my problem is to generate invoice from monday-sunday
on every Sunday night at 23:59:00

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779402/4258328

Comment: Thanks Christophe resolved the issue